# How to cascade Spring Cloud Dataflow streams?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I know I can use fan in and fan out notation in Streams DSL to cascade multiple flow modifiers in the same stream, like:

```
s3 > :data
ftp > :data
http > :data
:data > file
```

However, supposing I have stream1 and stream2 registered, each one with their own DSL, how can I cascade both, doing something similar?

For instance:

## stream1 DSL:

```
time | transform | file
```

## stream2 DSL:

```
file | filter | http
```

Then I want to create something like stream3:

```
stream1 | stream2 | s3
```

Meaning both `time` and `file` would be read, and results would be written to `file`, `http` and `s3`. Is it possible?

I am assuming besides writing to the sinks I specified, `stream1` and `stream2` would also be writing back to pipe, so I would be able to cascade them and call them from `stream3`.

**EDIT - Problem I am trying to solve.**

As asked in the comments, let me detail what kind of problem I am trying to solve here.

The organization where I work has complex flows, 1 team doesn't maintain the whole thing, there are data producers teams, which take care of generating data from sources, and until the final data consumer there are usually many teams inferring data, transforming, normalizing, etc.

`stream1`, in my case, would be maintained by 1 team in the company, `steam2` by other team and `stream3` by my platform.

Although the teams maintaining each flow are independent, technically I still want the benefits from the in-memory pipelining when aggregating different flows. Of course, I expect to have to manage myself problems like - team 1 releases a new version of `stream1` that will require a new version of `stream2` - that's fine for my use case - my team could take care of that.

Comment: Could you edit the post and clarify the reasons behind this requirement? Is it "reuse"? If it is reuse, do you still care for independent scaling or rolling-upgrade of apps in the pipeline? If not, what do you gain by chaining?

Comment: Just did, please tell me whether there is any part which still needs clarification

Comment: Thanks for the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approaches to solve this.

*Option 1:* Combine the responsibilities of processor + sink into a "processor"; if that's done, you'd be able to consume the ingest (or) ingest + processing (or) ingest + processing + write as separate fragments of a streaming pipeline, and be able to use them in the DSL or in the GUI. The drawback of the composition here, of course, is the inability to independently interact and upgrade business logic, which might not be a problem for a few use-cases. In other words, you don't necessarily need them as individual microservices - it is perfectly fine if the responsibilities are thin, to compose them in a single App.

*Option 2:* Don't use SCDF. Build a similar set of Apps as discussed previously and orchestrate them as standalone Apps. You won't have to deal with the source, processor, or sink contracts in SCDF, so you will have the flexibility to plug the Apps in any manner you wish. The drawback here is the manual orchestration. The data pipeline visibility for monitoring is another thing. See example [here](https://github.com/sabbyanandan/eda/blob/master/userconsumer/src/main/java/com/example/consumer/Application.java#L17). If you still want to use it in SCDF, though it may not be ideal, there's a workaround - see [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2331#issuecomment-406444350).

*Option 3:* You can also build an integration-flow using Spring Integration, and build that into an SCSt App. This could give more granular controls, but you'd have to orchestrate them individually like in Option-2. Here's an [example](https://github.com/sabbyanandan/springonetour2018/blob/master/SIK/src/main/java/com/example/SIK/SpringIntegrationKafkaApplication.java#L51-L64).

Comment: Just to be clear about it - by "manual orchestration"  in option 2 you mean instead of using in-memory pipelining from SCDF I would have to use a message queue? Or is there an easy way of creating the in-memory pipeline "manually" using spring integration?

Comment: The Spring Cloud Stream Apps, whether or not deployed manually or through SCDF, they communicate with one another via Message Brokers like Kafka, RabbitMQ, or others. If you want to chain a series of operations and run them in a single JVM; basically you'd want them to be on the same thread, you'd do that via Spring Integration Flow, as shown in the example. As for "manual orchestration", I meant this from the perspective of you having to deploy them on to cloud platforms using scripts and/or CI/CD tooling. If SCDF in use, it'd provide this out-of-the-box, and I tried to list the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Router sink to connect streams. @sabby?

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-modules/tree/master/router-sink